# Unstable 5G wi-fi connection on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wireless

There are some questions here with similar issues, but none that I've tried so far have solved my problem. 
I have a dual boot Ideapad 320 that I use for work and university and a 120GB internet connection at home with 2G and 5G. At work, it works just fine with a 240GB connection, and at home too. But some days ago, when connected to the 5G network, my internet on Ubuntu would become very unstable and barely reaching the 10GB. On 2G it worked fine but with slower internet, obviously.
 I "worked" around this by connecting a LAN cable to it and then disconnecting, so with this I could get the connection I was having before, but this doesn't seem like an efficient fix to the issue as it keeps repeating.


Wireless card info : 
 description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 31
       serial: 00:05:16:59:32:93
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.3.0-40-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip='IP' latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11

Comment: 5Ghz actually does worse at distances and struggles more with any physical objects between the router and the device (walls, people, furniture, etc).  This is due to the smaller wavelength and can result in instablity or slower speeds.  I would recommend doing a few trials with your antenna in clear line of sight of the router, just to make sure that this is not what you are experiencing

Comment: @Nmath, my router is no further than a meter from me and nothing significant in its way. I can try to get an older antenna for it tomorrow and give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: So I changed the router antenna and put it closer to my laptop, but still suffering from an unstable connection on Ubuntu.